# When I'm running my program I'm getting out of memory error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, while-loop

So, I actually wanna create a timer which will count back time, but when I'm running this script I'm always getting the 'Out of memory' error. Here is my onClick script:

```
handleClickStart = () => {
          while (this.state.hours > 0) {
              this.setState({
                  hours: this.state.hours - 1
              })
          } 
    }
```

Also I could show you the whole code if you'd need it

Comment: [Beware: React setState is asynchronous! (medium.com)](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous and it runs in batches, don't use `setState` inside a loop, rather create a new variable and set state at the end of the loop, like this

```
handleClickStart = () => {
    let hours = this.state.hours;
    while (hours > 0) {
        hours --;
    } 

    this.setState({hours});
}
```